# How do I get the thread id of XMPP chat thread?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, xmpp, facebook-chat

I've implemented an XMPP Facebook chat in a browser and I wish to get the unseen messages on chat thread when I open a chat with a particular user, knowing his uid. I know this can be done by Graph API, but how do I know if this is a chat thread? Also only checking thread's 'from' field is wrong, because thread could be started by the user itself.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If it is part of a thread the messages will contain a  element, which is the id for the actual thread.

Comment: The question was - how to retrieve message's thread id having XMPP chat stream containing this message (only info available via XMPP), or how to identify among number of threads in /me/inbox which is containing the XMPP message in question. Did you propose searching for the message in all available threads by content and then taking its id? This should be used on desktop application and traffic does matter.

Comment: Same question here. Don't know how to properly map incoming messages to a certain conversation window.